# When manually triggering a KVO event, can the change dictionary be amended?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I have a data model, composed mostly of an NSMutableArray 'contents' and NSMutableDictionary 'contentsByName'. I have ViewController objects that I wish to observe changes in the data model.

I have a property "count" on the model that returns the size of the array 'contents' and I can trigger a KVO change observation with willChange: and didChange:. So far, so good. However, the view-controllers are now aware that the model has changed, but do not know what's been added to it. Ideally, I need to put extra information into the change dictionary that's delivered to the observer.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solvable by updating the model objects in a more granular way; however, built-in collections don't generate KVO notifications when their contents are modified, and will require some manual support.

If you want to generate notifications about changes to the array, use [willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCHFHHJ) and [didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002299-BBCBEFIJ) whenever it's modified. When these methods are used, the change dictionary will contain an entry for `NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey`, which reflects the indexes of insertion, deletion, or replacement.

If you want to generate notifications about changes to the dictionary, you can call `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` on the dictionary itself, like so:

```
- (void)addContent:(id)content {
    NSString *key = [content name];

    [self.contentsByName willChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self.contentsByName setValue:content forKey:key];
    [self.contentsByName didChangeValueForKey:key];
}
```

Any observer can also use `NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew` or `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` to receive the new or old values, respectively.